# winium not able find the web element using xpath

Tags: xpath

This code is not working while i am trying to execute using find element by xpath but the same is working with commented line where i have identified the element by name. 
Please suggest me whats wrong with this xpath.

```
WebElement ele1 = null;
ele = driver.findElement(By.name("Unified Service Desk for Microsoft Dynamics 365"));

WebElement ele2 = ele.findElement(By.xpath("*[@Name = 'Password']"));

//driver.findElement(By.name("Password")).sendKeys("P@ssw0rd123");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have already tried this is also not working.

Comment: Please can you share HTML code

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath

```
//*[@name='Password']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:
//*[contains(@Name,'Password')]
This worked for me.